# How do I make Bottom Sheet cover whole screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Jetpack Compose and trying to make a Login Screen cover the whole screen when the user clicks the login button in the `TopAppBar`.

I am using a combination of `ModalBottomSheetLayout` and a `Scaffold` so I can have a `TopAppBar` and a `BottomAppBar`.

Currently when the login screen is displayed it only covers half of the screen.

```
                       val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                        val bottomState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
                        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
                            sheetState = bottomState,
                            sheetShape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
                            sheetContent = {
                                FullScreen()
                            }
                        ) {

                            Scaffold(
                                topBar = {
                                    TopAppBar(
...
                                content = {

                                    NavHost(navController = navController,
                                        startDestination = "journey") {
                                        composable("journey") { JourneyScreen() }
...
                               bottomBar = {
                                    BottomAppBar(
                                        content = {
                                            BottomNavigation() {

                                                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
...
```

```
@Composable
fun FullScreen() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text("Full Screen")
    }
}
```

Have been stuck on this for way too long and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nice edits, thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `animateTo` is now internal.

With M3 (`1.1.0`) you can use the **`expand`** method

```
scope.launch { state.expand() }
```

With M2 (`1.4.0`) and M3 (`1.1.0`) you can set the attribute **`skipHalfExpanded`** to `true`

```
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHalfExpanded = true
)
```

and then use the **`show`** method:

```
scope.launch { state.show() }
```

---

Before M2 (`1.4.0`)  to have a fullscreen `ModalBottomSheetLayout`, instead of `state.show()` you can use:

```
scope.launch { state.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded) }
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. I could not find this in the docs anywhere and spent a long time on it.

Comment: Is it correct to say with ModalButtonSheetLayout you can't interact with the content underneath? What is if you need to interact with the content and want to expand die BottomSheet if needed?

Comment: This worked like a charm! I would vote 10 times if I could for this answer! Thank you

Comment: this works !!! great. After using this i went and checked the show() method and from the doc it is doing as expected.

Comment: /**Show the bottom sheet with animation and suspend until it's shown. If the sheet is taller than 50% of the parent's height, the bottom sheet will be half expanded. Otherwise it will be fully expanded.**/

Comment: It's internal now :(

Comment: @Mbt925 you can use `state.expand()` or `state.show()` if `skipHalfExpanded = true`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti `state.expand()` has been made internal too. `state.show()` doesn't do what we're looking for.

Comment: @Mbt925 `expand` is public with M3. If you are using M2, you have to use `state.show()` specifying `skipHalfExpanded = true`. As described in the doc, if `true`, the sheet will always expand to the `Expanded` state and move to the
 `Hidden` state when hiding the sheet,  either programmatically or by user interaction.

Answer (score 3):

The `animateTo` method is internal and cannot be used anymore. To expand the bottom sheet set `skipHalfExpanded` to true:

```
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHalfExpanded = true,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI... As appear in [SheetState documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/SheetState), now with `Material3 v1.2.0` set `skipPartiallyExpanded = true` if you need ModalBottomSheet full screen. Nothing else required:

```
@Composable
fun CompendiumItem(
   modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
   entry: CompendiumListEntry
) {
   val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true)
   var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

   Box(modifier = modifier
      .padding(top = 30.dp)
      .clickable {
         showBottomSheet = true
      }
   ) {
      ...

   if (showBottomSheet) {
      ModalBottomSheet(
         onDismissRequest = {
            showBottomSheet = false
         },
         sheetState = sheetState
      ) {
         ItemDetailScreen(itemId = entry.id)
      }
   }
}
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).